# 'scons' not recognisable on command line

Tags: python, windows, scons

So I installed python-3.10.7 on a fresh windows 10 PC, then used `pip install scons` to install scons but I keep getting the following error when I type `scons` in terminal.

```
C:\Users\tempm>scons
'scons' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Ive added `C:\Users\tempm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts` and also `C:\Users\tempm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` to my PATH environment variable with no luck still. Scons seems to have been installed in `C:\Users\tempm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\SCons\Script` and I''ve added every directory under SCon to my evironment variable with still no luck.

My python script directory looks like so:

```
 Directory of C:\Users\tempm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

16/09/2022  02:23 PM    <DIR>          .
16/09/2022  02:23 PM    <DIR>          ..
16/09/2022  02:23 PM           107,912 pip.exe
16/09/2022  02:23 PM           107,912 pip3.10.exe
16/09/2022  02:23 PM           107,912 pip3.exe
               3 File(s)        323,736 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  83,683,979,264 bytes free
```

And I believe there should be an scons.exe there but I cant find it anywhere.

When I try `pip install scons` again i get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scons in c:\users\tempm\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\tempm\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scons) (63.2.0)
```

If anyone has any idea of anything else I could try that would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks for sll your comments. I this should be the answer, but installing scons through pip on python3.10 just didn't give me an scons.exe, so I installed python3.8 and pip installed scons through that, and then it showed up in scripts! Maybe there is a bug with python3.10 but at least its solved.

**PLEASE WHEN YOU INSTALL PYTHON** make sure you check the box that asks you if you want to add it to your environment variables, especially if you are on a fresh machine, just to save you any mistakes or headaches trying to find where to add it and what to add.

Comment: You probably shouldn't edit an answer into the question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387723/answer-a-question-inside-the-question

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you're looking for the file `scons.exe`.
If your configuration is like mine, it is in the directory `C:\Users\tempm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` but the exact location depends on how exactly you've installed it.

When you have the correct path added, restart `cmd` or whatever other program you need to have the path in. Windows won't update the `PATH` variable until a program is restarted.

To check if the `PATH` variable is updated in `cmd`, you can use the command `echo %Path%` which displays it's content.
To see if the shell is able to find SCons, type `where scons` (or you may just try to run SCons and see if it works).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I this should be the answer, but installing scons through pip on python3.10 just didn't give me an scons.exe, so I installed python3.8 and pip installed scons through that, and then it showed up in scripts! Maybe there is a bug with python3.10 but at least its solved.

Comment: @Shizo If you suspect you've found a bug, you should report you on the SCons Discord server (https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy) and even if this won't turn out to be a bug, you will get help there. Just make sure to report the solution back here for others to find :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python -mSCons --version
```

(Assuming your installed python is in your path)

You could also try

```
py -3.10 -MSCons --version
```

Comment: What does this do? It does print some "SCons path". Is this the path where the SCons executable is located?

Comment: No. It's another way of running any installed python package and then providing command line arguments to it.  `--version` is just an argument to SCons.  So if you want to do a build, just cd into your source tree, and run `py -3.10 -MSCons` and it should build.